# Laravel Join table and query

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 table. Users, Accounts and Booking. I have try three table join and year and month wise query. [3 Table diagram][1]

But query booking calculation is show wrong. It's showing double quantity.

```
$january = DB::table('users')
        ->join('bookings', 'users.id', '=', 'bookings.user_id')
        ->join('accounts', 'users.id', '=', 'accounts.user_id')
        ->orderBy('users.room_id','asc')
        ->groupBy('users.id')
        ->whereYear('bookings.bookingdate','=', '2016')
        ->whereMonth('bookings.bookingdate','=','01')
        ->whereYear('accounts.accountdate','=', '2016')
        ->whereMonth('accounts.accountdate','=','01')
        ->select('users.*',
            DB::raw("COUNT(case when bookings.breakfast='on' then 1 else null end) AS t_breakfast"),
            DB::raw("COUNT(case when bookings.lunch='on' then 1 else null end) AS t_lunch"),
            DB::raw("COUNT(case when bookings.dinner='on' then 1 else null end) AS t_dinner"),
            DB::raw("SUM(accounts.amount) AS t_amount")
        )
        ->get();

    dd($january);
```

My Accounts  table is:
[Accounts Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gh57.png)
My Booking table is:
[Bookings Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gNCP.png)

When I'm run this query it's show:

```
+"t_breakfast": "2"
+"t_lunch": "2"
+"t_dinner": "2"
+"t_amount": "22.00"
```

But I need t_breakfast, t_lunch, t_dinner quantity is: 1. But It's showing double.

Comment: When you say it shows double quantity, are you referring to t_amount?

Comment: Hi, I am edit and add the more details in my post. please look my post.

Comment: did you resolve your issue?

Comment: When I try one query I did not solved this problem. then I try two query and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

When I try one query I did not solved this problem. then I try two query and solved it.

```
$data = DB::select("SELECT users.id, users.name , users.picture, users.room_id,
        SUM(CASE WHEN bookings.breakfast='on' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS t_b ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN bookings.lunch='on' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS t_l ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN bookings.dinner='on' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS t_d FROM `users`
    INNER JOIN
    `bookings` ON users.id=bookings.user_id AND
    MONTH(bookings.bookingdate) = $month AND
    YEAR(bookings.bookingdate) = $year

    GROUP BY users.id
    ORDER BY users.room_id ASC");

    $datas = [];
    $data = json_decode(json_encode($data),true);
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $x = [];
        $x = $value;
        $x['exp'] = Account::where('user_id',$x['id'])->whereMonth('accountdate','=',$month)->whereYear('accountdate','=',$year)->sum('amount');
        $datas[] = $x;
    }

    $total_t_b = $total_t_l = $total_t_d = $total_exp = 0;
    foreach ($datas as $data) {
        $total_t_b += $data['t_b'];
        $total_t_l += $data['t_l'];
        $total_t_d += $data['t_d'];
        $total_exp += $data['exp'];

    }
    $g_total = $total_t_b + $total_t_l + $total_t_d;

    if($g_total <= 0) {
        $perbookingprice = 0;
    } else {
        $perbookingprice = $total_exp / $g_total;
    }
```